# Why is a warning is thrown when running a piece of code using php-cli, but a warning is not thrown when running the exact same code using PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, warnings

I have some code that I run via a normal file using the `php` cli and `phpunit`.

What baffles me is that the code should throw a warning during execution, but it never throws the warning in PHPUnit.

This is the code that when run using `php run.php` will throw a warning:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style type="text/css">

a:active {
    font-size: 11px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="google.com">blah</a>
</body>
</html>';

$htmldoc = new InlineStyle\InlineStyle($html);
$htmldoc->applyStylesheet($htmldoc->extractStylesheets()); //Causes a warning

echo($htmldoc->getHTML());
```

The warning:

```
Warning: array_map(): An error occurred while invoking the map callback in /work/inlinecss-test/vendor/symfony/css-selector/Symfony/Component/CssSelector/XPath/Translator.php
```

It doesn't matter if I run the file through `php-fpm` or `php`, a warning will be thrown.

However, if I put the code into a PHPUnit test case and run it, no warning is thrown:

```
<?php
use InlineStyle\InlineStyle;

class InlineStyleTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testActivePseudoSelectors(){
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

a:active {
    font-size: 11px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="google.com">blah</a>
</body>
</html>';

        $htmldoc = new InlineStyle($html);
        $styles = $htmldoc->extractStylesheets();

        $htmldoc->applyStylesheet($styles);


        echo($htmldoc->getHTML());
    }
}
```

In this case the test is fine and no warnings were thrown:

```
OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
```

This is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="tests">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

What could be the cause of this discrepancy?

The code is in this repo: https://github.com/F21/inlinecss-test

The results of running the above is on travis-ci: https://travis-ci.org/F21/inlinecss-test/jobs/17397488

Comment: I believe PHPUnit forces all the warnings to be off, so they are only in the logs.

Comment: @StevenScott In my config, I have set it so that `convertWarningsToExceptions = true`. hmmm.

Comment: This may be due to how you are trying to run it.  PHPUnit uses its own internal logic and handling for the Globals, maybe that stops the error_reporting(), but I think you should see the exceptions based on your bootstrap.  Maybe try something simple in code (require/include) in a test file?

Answer (score -1):

PHPUnit converts errors/warnings/notices to exceptions so that they can show up in the test results.

[PHPUnit Docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

Comment: That is true. But if a warning is thrown and then converted to an exception, it should show up since I am not catching it. For example, if I triggered a warning using `trigger_error()`, it shows up with I run the test.